# Communicate between BackgroundWorker and main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I wonder how to start my Server connection (simple button click that take 2 sec) without my UI freeze and after the connection established update my UI, i can do it via `BackgroundWorker` and inside `worker_RunWorkerCompleted event` update my UI but because this is different thread i need to use `Invoke`:

```
 private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnConnect.Enabled = false;
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Start do work and connect:

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Establish the connection...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And after the connection established update my UI:

```
private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Update UI
}
```

My question is can i avoid using invoke ?
because in my application i have several points that i need to add, remove, update labels, DatagridView and in this way i'll have using `Invoke` several times, this is a common and proper to do this? 
There is a way to start something in different thread and after this thread ends remain to the main thread ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need `Invoke` in the following callbacks:

- `ProgressChanged`
- `RunWorkerCompleted`

Here you can access the UI elements directly without problems. The rest needs `Invoke`.